# How to create a ChatOverViiew Query with FirebaseDatabase not loading the whole databse

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I my Android app I am using the `FirebaseDatabse` to write a chat application. The structure of data is:

```
"message": {
    "user1_guid": {
        "user2_guid": {
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            ...
        },
        "user_n_guid": {
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            ...
        },
    },
    "user2_guid": {
        "user1_guid": {
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            ...
        },
        "user_n_guid": {
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            "messageGuid": < MessageObject > ,
            ...
        },
    }
}
```

To load chat-details of user1 I can just do:

```
final DatabaseReference lDatabaseReference = lDatabase
        .child("message")
        .child(sender)
        .child(mChatPartnerGuid);
```

and load it into A `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(MessageData,ChatDetailsAdapter.MessageViewHolder)`

But What I want now is to make a `ChatOverviewFragment`. It shall show only the latest message of each user there is a conversation in the database (just like in WhatsApp). Using a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` would mean the whole database has to be download within all messages of all conversations there might be...

Isn't there a better way to do a query that just filter for that very first message of every user the active user is in conversation with? Especially I don>'t know how to load it into a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` then. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to adapt your db structure to make it meet your needs. What I would do, is to create a node containing, for each user, the latest message received by each user. to reduce "useless" redundancy and avoid corrupted data, I would change what you built and shared with us so far too.

```
"messages": {
    "messageId": {
        "text": string,
        "date": long,
        "sender": string,
        "receiver": string
    }
},
"last-messages": {
    "userReceiver": {
        "sender1": messageId,
        "sender2": messageId,
        [...]
    },
    [...]
}
```

if you want to sort them by request, just change the `"sender1": messageId` to `"sender1": { "messageId": messageId", "date":long}`

Comment: This means redundant data, but as long as there is no suitable way to create an RecyclerAdapter, I do it that way

Answer (score 0):

well, if I correctly understand what you're asking for, maybe the [limitToLast](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) method, using 1 as param, could do the job, if you're using push() to create ids for messages

Comment: Doesn't that just limit the number of results - what I don't want to?